# Making a request to the mojang API with go gives a 403

Tags: go

I'm very new to golang, but I'm trying to make a http GET request to the mojang api to get the UUID of a player name. This is my code.

```golang
func getHTTP(url string) (response string) {

    client := &http.Client{}

    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
    if err != nil {
        return string(err.Error())
    }

    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return string(err.Error())
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    body, e := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return string(e.Error())
    }

    return string(body)
}

func main() {
  fmt.Printf(getHTTP("https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/paultje52"))
}
```

What I get is a html document with a 403 error (Request blocked), like you can see here.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>403 ERROR</H1>
<H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>
<HR noshade size="1px">
Request blocked.
We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
<BR clear="all">
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
<BR clear="all">
<HR noshade size="1px">
<PRE>
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: JxLUo2aufLong500lqBzESwB0yKSV4aE8DReo3g-0arxXmJSfS5c8g==
</PRE>
<ADDRESS>
</ADDRESS>
</BODY></HTML>
```

But when I go to the exact same URL with google chrome or postman (same machine with the same ip), I get a normal response from the mojang API.

```
{
    "name": "Paultje52",
    "id": "895933a3f98b4bd697515673a04d632e"
}
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong or is this an issue with go? Or blocks CloudFront requests made by go?

Comment: Why do you add a content type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's look like the website blocked the default user-agent.
use the following line to change it and everything will work fine

```
req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "test")
```